# Avoid the if condition in checking multiple lists and limiting the results in python

Tags: python, list

I have a scenario where I have multiple lists of dictionaries. Any of the lists can be empty. I want to iterate through all the lists sequentially and take the first 5 names.

For example,

```
list1 = [{'name': 'user1'}]
list2 = []
list3 = [{'name': 'user2'}, {'name': 'user3'}]
list4 = [{'name': 'user4'}, {'name': 'user5'}, {'name': 'user6'}]
list5 = []
list6 = [{'name': 'user7'}, {'name': 'user8'}]
```

In these different list, the values are derived from another list comprehension condition, so they may be empty, as `list2` and `list6`.

I want to take the first 5 names considering all these lists. The idea is:

```
final_list = []
list1 = [{'name': 'user1'}]
if list1:
    final_list.append(list1)

list2 = []
if list2:
    final_list.append(list2)

list3 = [{'name': 'user2'}, {'name': 'user3'}]
if list3:
    final_list.append(list3)

list4 = [{'name': 'user4'}, {'name': 'user5'}, {'name': 'user6'}]
if list4:
    final_list.append(list4)

list5 = []
if list5:
    final_list.append(list5)

list6 = [{'name': 'user7'}, {'name': 'user8'}]
if list6:
    final_list.append(list6)

for name in final_list:
    # iterate and get the names and limit the results to 5
```

But this one has multiple `if` conditions. Is there any better approach in terms of standard and performance to avoid the if checking on the list empty condition like the one that I did? Appreciate your suggestions or directions, or code, I can work out.

Comment: Do you have control of the data structures here? Why are you using dictionaries?

Comment: thanks for your response, I don't have a control on the data structure, it is an output from the an api service iteration

Comment: Can you collect it into a list instead of having 6 separate variables?

Comment: Also, you're allowed to change your selection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
k = 0
final_list = [ j['name']  for i in [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6] for j in i if (k:=k+1)<=5]
```

Edit: I misunderstood the question. There's also no need of writing if list... If list is empty, there will b no iteration.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Using a double for loop**

```
l = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6] # Aggregating the lists
names = []                                     # Resulting names
max_names = 5
for lst in l:
    for dic in lst:
        names.append(dic['name'])     # Extract name
        if len(names) == max_names:    
            break                     # done with inner loop, since at limit
    else:
        continue                      # no break in inner loop, so keep going
    break                             # stop outer loop, since break in inner loop
        
print(*names, sep = ', ')
 # Out: user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
```

**Option 2: Using Generator**

```
def fun_gen(*l):
    '''
        Create generator for names in sublists of l
    '''
    for sublist in l:
        for d in sublist:
            yield d['name']
            
# Generator for names
names = fun_gen(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6)

# Print first five
print(*[next(names) for _ in range(5)], sep = ', ')
# Out: user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
```

Comment: appreciate your quick response too

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) here. Specifically, [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) are your friend:

```
from itertools import chain, islice

[x['name'] for x in islice(chain(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6), 5)]
```

`chain` makes an iterable that will go through your lists one-by-one, regardless of what they contain. It is a generator, so does not evaluate anything until you tell it to. `islice` will only iterate through the first `n=5` elements of the `chain`. That means that you will end up inspecting the first five elements and only the first five elements.